# Error to login via twitter (modx)

Tags: twitter, sdk, oauth, modx-revolution

I have a site in modx revo. Developed its own authorization via twitter. Used the SDK (https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth/). How it works: The request to Twitter. After returning to twitter check if a new user on the site. If so, create a user and create a session on the site. If not, simply create a session.

But this is not working properly.
1. Once he gives an error on a request

```
  $code = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', $tmhOAuth->url('oauth/access_token', ''), array(
    'oauth_verifier' => $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']
  ));

  if ($code == 200) {
```

1. Next time, nothing happens!
2. The next time the login is performed perfectly.

These actions are executed cyclically every time. 1-2-3 steps.

What is the problem? What is not working?

The code of the plugin:

```
<?php

require MODX_CORE_PATH.'components/twPost/tmhOAuth.php';
require MODX_CORE_PATH.'components/twPost/tmhUtilities.php';

$tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array(
  'consumer_key'    => '*************',
  'consumer_secret' => '**************',
));

$contexts = empty($contexts) ? array($modx->context->get('key')) : explode(',', $contexts);

if(isset($_SESSION['access_token']) ){
    $tmhOAuth->config['user_token']  = $_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token'];
    $tmhOAuth->config['user_secret'] = $_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret'];

    $code = $tmhOAuth->request('GET', $tmhOAuth->url('1/account/verify_credentials'));
    if ($code == 200) {
        $user_data = json_decode($tmhOAuth->response['response']);
        $moduser = $modx->getObject('modUser',  array('remote_key:=' => $user_data->id, 'remote_key:!=' => null));
        if(empty($moduser)){
            $homet = '';
            if(!empty($user_data->location)){
                $hometownAr = explode(',',$user_data->location);
                $homet = $hometownAr[0];
            }

            $moduser = $modx->newObject('modUser');
            $moduser->set('username', $user_data->screen_name);
            $moduser->set('active', true);
            $moduser->set('remote_key', $user_data->id);
            $moduser->set('remote_data', (array)$user_data);


            $profile = $modx->newObject('modUserProfile');
            $profile->set('email', $user_data->screen_name.'@twitter.com');
            $profile->set('fullname', $user_data->name);
            $profile->set('city', $homet);
            $profile->set('photo', $user_data->profile_image_url);

            $moduser->addOne($profile, 'Profile');
            $saved = $moduser->save();
        }

        $_SESSION['oauth_token']  = $_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret'];

        $moduser->set('active',1);
        $moduser->save();

        foreach ($contexts as $context) {
            $moduser->addSessionContext($context);
        }

        $url = $_SESSION['back_url_login'];
        if(empty($url)) $url = "/";
        unset($_SESSION['back_url_login']);
        $modx->sendRedirect($url);        
    } else {
        $_SESSION['error_upform'] = 'Login error. Please try again. Main';
        $modx->sendRedirect('/');
    }

} elseif (isset($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'])) {
  $tmhOAuth->config['user_token']  = $_SESSION['oauth']['oauth_token'];
  $tmhOAuth->config['user_secret'] = $_SESSION['oauth']['oauth_token_secret'];

  $code = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', $tmhOAuth->url('oauth/access_token', ''), array(
    'oauth_verifier' => $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']
  ));

  if ($code == 200) {
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $tmhOAuth->extract_params($tmhOAuth->response['response']);
    unset($_SESSION['oauth']);
    $modx->sendRedirect('/?id=12');
  } else {
        $_SESSION['error_upform'] = 'Login error. Please try again. verifier. | '.$tmhOAuth->response['response'];
        $modx->sendRedirect('/');
  }
// start the OAuth dance
}elseif ( isset($_REQUEST['auth']) && $_REQUEST['auth']=='1' ) {
    $_SESSION['back_url_login'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

    $params = array(
        'oauth_callback'     => '/?id=12'
    );

    $params['x_auth_access_type'] = 'write';
    //$params['x_auth_access_type'] = 'read';

    $code = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', $tmhOAuth->url('oauth/request_token', ''), $params);

    if ($code == 200) {
        $_SESSION['oauth'] = $tmhOAuth->extract_params($tmhOAuth->response['response']);
        $method = 'authorize'; $force  = '';
        $authurl = $tmhOAuth->url("oauth/{$method}", '') .  "?oauth_token={$_SESSION['oauth']['oauth_token']}{$force}";
        $modx->sendRedirect($authurl);
  } else {
        $_SESSION['error_upform'] = 'Login error. Please try again.';
        $modx->sendRedirect('/');
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this a snippet? Is it cached? `[[!yourTwitterSnippet]]` should be the correct way to call this.

Comment: This is a simple page on which this snippet is only called (for example www.mysite.com/index.php?id=12). Without the cache. Just [[!meTwitterSnippet]]

Comment: In your $moduser = $modx->getObject, your criteria is this

`array('remote_key:=' => $user_data->id, 'remote_key:!=' => null)`

while that should be:

`array('remote_key:=' => $user_data->id, 'AND:remote_key:!=' => null)`

When you specify the between the field and value (in your case !=), you also need to specify if it is AND or OR. Otherwise it may not generate the proper SQL statement.

Don't think this is the actual cause of the issue you describe, but should be fixed anyway.

Comment: Big thanks Mark. It does not solve my main problem. But it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
'oauth_token' => $_REQUEST['oauth_token']
```

to your request. Like this:

```
$code = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', $tmhOAuth->url('oauth/access_token', ''), array(
    'oauth_verifier' => $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'],
    'oauth_token' => $_REQUEST['oauth_token']
));
```

Without this line twitter wasn't working for me at all.